# Use Nette form with material design

Tags: angularjs, material-design, nette

I've recently bought angular theme admin.io (https://themeforest.net/item/adminio-responsive-material-design-admin/10761963) which I would like to use with PHP Nette framework. Everything goes well with text inputs and buttons by manual rendering. But I got stuck with select element.
It should look like this:

```
<md-select ng-model="someVal" name="priority" placeholder="Zvolte prioritu">
     <md-option value="1">Urgent</md-option>
     <md-option value="2">Vysoká</md-option>
     <md-option value="3">Střední</md-option>
     <md-option value="4">Nízká</md-option>
</md-select>
```

but Nette renders it as basic `<select>`. I could render select with `<md-select n:name="">`, but there is problem with rendering options. Is there any way how to manually render `<option>` as I did with select and whole form, or can I use my own template for that form, or please, someone knows, how to make this work? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be little difficult. Nette SelectBox isn't built for this. You need to construct your own Control. You can use `Nette\Forms\Controls\SelectBox` as template and make few adjustments:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Forms;

use Nette;


/**
 * Select box control that allows single item selection.
 */
class MdSelectBox extends Nette\Forms\Controls\ChoiceControl
{
    /** validation rule */
    const VALID = ':selectBoxValid';

    /** @var array of option / optgroup */
    private $options = [];

    /** @var mixed */
    private $prompt = false;

    /** @var array */
    private $optionAttributes = [];


    public function __construct($label = null, array $items = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($label, $items);
        $this->setOption('type', 'md-select');
        $this->addCondition(Nette\Forms\Form::BLANK)
            ->addRule([$this, 'isOk'], Nette\Forms\Validator::$messages[self::VALID]);
    }


    /**
     * Sets first prompt item in select box.
     * @param  string|object
     * @return static
     */
    public function setPrompt($prompt)
    {
        $this->prompt = $prompt;
        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * Returns first prompt item?
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPrompt()
    {
        return $this->prompt;
    }


    /**
     * Sets options and option groups from which to choose.
     * @return static
     */
    public function setItems(array $items, $useKeys = true)
    {
        if (!$useKeys) {
            $res = [];
            foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
                unset($items[$key]);
                if (is_array($value)) {
                    foreach ($value as $val) {
                        $res[$key][(string) $val] = $val;
                    }
                } else {
                    $res[(string) $value] = $value;
                }
            }
            $items = $res;
        }
        $this->options = $items;
        return parent::setItems(Nette\Utils\Arrays::flatten($items, true));
    }


    /**
     * Generates control's HTML element.
     * @return Nette\Utils\Html
     */
    public function getControl()
    {
        $items = $this->prompt === false ? [] : ['' => $this->translate($this->prompt)];
        foreach ($this->options as $key => $value) {
            $items[is_array($value) ? $this->translate($key) : $key] = $this->translate($value);
        }

        return Helpers::createSelectBox(
            $items,
            [
                'disabled:' => is_array($this->disabled) ? $this->disabled : null,
            ] + $this->optionAttributes,
            $this->value
        )->addAttributes(parent::getControl()->attrs);
    }


    /**
     * @return static
     */
    public function addOptionAttributes(array $attributes)
    {
        $this->optionAttributes = $attributes + $this->optionAttributes;
        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isOk()
    {
        return $this->isDisabled()
            || $this->prompt !== false
            || $this->getValue() !== null
            || !$this->options
            || $this->control->size > 1;
    }
}
```

You also need to rewrite `Nette\Forms\Helpers` class, which is main reason you can't achieve this with `Nette\Forms\Controls\SelectBox`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Forms;

use Nette;
use Nette\Utils\Html;


/**
 * Forms helpers.
 */
class Helpers
{
    use Nette\StaticClass;


    /**
     * @return Html
     */
    public static function createSelectBox(array $items, array $optionAttrs = null, $selected = null)
    {
        if ($selected !== null) {
            $optionAttrs['selected?'] = $selected;
        }
        list($optionAttrs, $optionTag) = self::prepareAttrs($optionAttrs, 'md-option');
        $option = Html::el();
        $res = $tmp = '';
        foreach ($items as $group => $subitems) {
            if (is_array($subitems)) {
                $res .= Html::el('md-optgroup')->label($group)->startTag();
                $tmp = '</md-optgroup>';
            } else {
                $subitems = [$group => $subitems];
            }
            foreach ($subitems as $value => $caption) {
                $option->value = $value;
                foreach ($optionAttrs as $k => $v) {
                    $option->attrs[$k] = isset($v[$value]) ? $v[$value] : null;
                }
                if ($caption instanceof Html) {
                    $caption = clone $caption;
                    $res .= $caption->setName('md-option')->addAttributes($option->attrs);
                } else {
                    $res .= $optionTag . $option->attributes() . '>'
                        . htmlspecialchars((string) $caption, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8')
                        . '</md-option>';
                }
                if ($selected === $value) {
                    unset($optionAttrs['selected'], $option->attrs['selected']);
                }
            }
            $res .= $tmp;
            $tmp = '';
        }
        return Html::el('md-select')->setHtml($res);
    }


    private static function prepareAttrs($attrs, $name)
    {
        $dynamic = [];
        foreach ((array) $attrs as $k => $v) {
            $p = str_split($k, strlen($k) - 1);
            if ($p[1] === '?' || $p[1] === ':') {
                unset($attrs[$k], $attrs[$p[0]]);
                if ($p[1] === '?') {
                    $dynamic[$p[0]] = array_fill_keys((array) $v, true);
                } elseif (is_array($v) && $v) {
                    $dynamic[$p[0]] = $v;
                } else {
                    $attrs[$p[0]] = $v;
                }
            }
        }
        return [$dynamic, '<' . $name . Html::el(null, $attrs)->attributes()];
    }
}
```

Then you can use you newly built `MdSelectBox` in your form like this:

```
$options = ['1' => 'Urgent', '2' => 'Medium', '3' => 'Low'];
$form->addComponent(new \App\Forms\MdSelectBox('Priority', $options), 'priority');
```

Or you can register your new control somewhere to use it directly on Form as `addMdSelectBox()`:

```
ObjectMixin::setExtensionMethod(Container::class, 'addMdSelectbox', function (Container $container, $name, $label = null, array $items = null) {
    return $container[$name] = new \App\Forms\MdSelectBox($label, $items);
});
```

Comment: Sorry for late answer. I've tried this, it works great, but md-select doesn't send its value to `onSuccess[]` function. Is there any way to send its values, or I will have to use normal select please?

Comment: Of course, because it's not normal select. Only way is, you send values using ajax call in JS.